# Фильтр повторяющихся значений по условию SQL

Tags: sql

Есть таблица:

[image: Когда каждый owner_id владел машиной car_id - начало и окончания владения]

Мне надо чтобы осталось первые строчки: это когда owner_id владел своей первой машиной, дальше повторения - это вторая по счету машина во владении. Я сортирую по start_date- первые 3 строчки не повторяются, остальные надо отбросить.

SELECT owner_id, car_id
FROM car_owner_period
ORDER BY start_date

Как сделать условие?

[image: результат]

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующее решение. Это для MS SQL Server.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL и образец вставки данных, начало
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
    car_id INT,
    owner_id INT,
    [start_date] DATE
);
INSERT INTO @tbl (car_id, owner_id, [start_date]) VALUES
(1, 1, '2016-04-12'),
(1, 2, '2016-10-17'),
(1, 3, '2016-12-19'),
(15, 2, '2016-04-12'),
(34, 3, '2016-04-12'),
(45, 1, '2016-10-17');
-- DDL и образец вставки данных, конец

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT *
        , seq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY owner_id ORDER BY [start_date] ASC)
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT rs.owner_id, rs.car_id 
FROM rs
WHERE seq = 1
ORDER BY rs.owner_id;
```

**Результат**

```
+----------+--------+
| owner_id | car_id |
+----------+--------+
|        1 |      1 |
|        2 |     15 |
|        3 |     34 |
+----------+--------+
```

Comment: Простите за вопрос, но это точно все надо тут или это просто в привычном вам стиле? (изучаю mySQL несколько дней,так что все в новинку - "а нам это не рассказывали!":-), хотя в нем все это тоже поддерживается, как понимаю). Например, `WITH`,  `ROW_NUMBER()`, `OVER`. `seq`, `PARTITION BY`? Как бы выглядел простой минимизированный код?

Comment: @Сергей,
Ответ демонстрирует тривиальный SQL. Если вы знаете альтернативное решение, поделитесь им в качестве дополнительного ответа.