# Как сравнить даты в полях строк для каждого сотрудника отдельно? SQL

Tags: sql

Есть таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо получить из нее вот такую выборку по заданию: Найти модель первой машины каждого из сотрудников  и выести в этих полях null, если у сотрудника никогда не было машины

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В чем конкретная сложность? Если бы задача была "Найти модель самой дешевой машины каждого из сотрудников и вывести в этих полях null, если у сотрудника никогда не было машины" - то знаете, как делать? Именно с датой проблема?

Comment: непонятно, как даты сравнивать не в строке по столбцам, а по строках с условием одно имя

Comment: Исправил заголовок. А то сбивал с толку и выглядел, как "сделайте мне домашку".

Comment: Я бы порылся в направлении чего-то типа `SELECT name, first_brand 
FROM table
WHERE start_date IN (SELECT MIN(start_date) FROM table GROUP BY name);` (синтаксис mySQL). Но я буквально два-три дня изучаю БД, так что могут быть сюрпризы.

Comment: Дубликат вопроса [Фильтр повторяющихся значений по условию SQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1431597/%d0%a4%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d1%80-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8e-sql)

Comment: да, min(start_date) ,будет подставлять значение со всего столбца

Comment: @Akina, не особо дубликат. Я тот ответ не смог использовать, да и, признаться, не очень понял. Может, потому, что там не mySQL, а может он просто на очень хорошем уровне написан, для начинающих непонятном.

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Comment: Oracle <> SQL Server <> MySQL <> DB2 <> Cosmos DB, и т.п.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky, относительно последнего вашего комментария выше: при переносе вашего кода, начиная с 'WITH' к БД mySQL (где работает мой ответ) получаю ошибку "ERROR 1054: Unknown column 'seq' in 'field list'". Откуда взялся 'field list'-  тоже непонятно. И до этого найти не смог в синтаксисе именно такого ввода sequence через SELECT. Предполагаю, что синтаксисы все же отличаются между версиями SQL. И спасибо за комментарий про CTE в ответе, стало яснее, а  неясность ответа для меня (возможно, и для Полины) была и в связи с уровнем ответа "не для новичка" и с синтаксисом.

Comment: MySQL v.8.0 поддерживает CTE: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html Разные СУБД поддерживают разные диалекты SQL. Вот почему когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример" ##1-4.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky, спасибо, но я говорю не про CTE полностью, а про конкретный синтаксис с `seq=` после `SELECT`. Но неважно. Наверняка, если и  так, то можно переписать в другом синтаксисе, только покопаться нужно. На всякий случай, если кто читать будет комментарии: статья по sequence в mySQL:<https://habr.com/ru/post/575044/>

Comment: @Сергей, пожалуйста, свяжитесь со мной на LinkedIn

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky, спасибо за предложение. Меня там нет, да и в любом случае нет смысла тратить ваше время на это. Я изучаю SQL всего несколько дней, даже курсы меньше половины ещё пройдены. Разберусь в таких вещах по мере понимания. Спасибо еще раз за все комментарии и за обновленный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующее решение. Это для MS SQL Server.

CTE создает сегменты для каждого сотрудника, упорядоченные по дате. Вот почему внешний SELECT использует seq=1, то есть модель первой машины.

Невидимый вывод из CTE:

```
+-----+--------+----------+------------+----+-------+-------------+-----+
| _ID | car_id | owner_id | start_date | id | _Name |    model    | seq |
+-----+--------+----------+------------+----+-------+-------------+-----+
|   1 | 1      | 1        | 2016-04-12 |  1 | John  | Volvo XC90  |   1 |
|   6 | 45     | 1        | 2016-10-17 |  1 | John  | Opel Astra  |   2 |
|   4 | 15     | 2        | 2016-04-12 |  2 | Kim   | Volvo XC90  |   1 |
|   2 | 1      | 2        | 2016-10-17 |  2 | Kim   | Volvo XC90  |   2 |
|   5 | 34     | 3        | 2016-04-12 |  3 | Smith | Opel Zafira |   1 |
|   3 | 1      | 3        | 2016-12-19 |  3 | Smith | Volvo XC90  |   2 |
|   7 | NULL   | NULL     | NULL       |  4 | Paul  | NULL        |   1 |
+-----+--------+----------+------------+----+-------+-------------+-----+
```

**SQL**

```
-- DDL и образец вставки данных, начало
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
    _ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
    car_id INT,
    owner_id INT,
    [start_date] DATE,
    id INT,
    _Name  VARCHAR(20),
    model VARCHAR(20)
);
INSERT INTO @tbl (car_id, owner_id, [start_date], id, _Name, model) VALUES
(1, 1, '2016-04-12', 1, 'John', 'Volvo XC90'),
(1, 2, '2016-10-17', 2, 'Kim', 'Volvo XC90'),
(1, 3, '2016-12-19', 3, 'Smith', 'Volvo XC90'),
(15, 2, '2016-04-12', 2, 'Kim', 'Volvo XC90'),
(34, 3, '2016-04-12', 3, 'Smith', 'Opel Zafira'),
(45, 1, '2016-10-17', 1, 'John', 'Opel Astra'),
(NULL, NULL, NULL, 4, 'Paul', NULL);
-- DDL и образец вставки данных, конец

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT *
        , seq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY [start_date] ASC)
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT _Name, model AS first_brand
FROM rs
WHERE seq = 1
ORDER BY id;
```

**Результат**

```
+-------+-------------+
| _Name | first_brand |
+-------+-------------+
| John  | Volvo XC90  |
| Kim   | Volvo XC90  |
| Smith | Opel Zafira |
| Paul  | NULL        |
+-------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Я все-таки доделал вывод (немного поумнев в процессе) - ниже код, как "даты сравнивать не в строке по столбцам, а по строках с условием одно имя". Отдельное спасибо @andreymal за обнаружение ошибки в синтаксисе у меня.

Код - в синтаксисе mySQL. Название вашей таблицы не знаю, тут использовал оригинальное имя table.

```
SELECT
    name,
    model AS first_brand   
FROM table
WHERE (name, start_date) 
    IN
    (   SELECT
            name, MIN(start_date)
        FROM
            table
        GROUP BY name
 )
```

Относительно вывода null - должна быть просто модификация строки 3 к `IFNULL (model,  null) AS first_brand`, но не проверить на моей учебной БД (там запрет на внесение записей с `NULL`).

Comment: Если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если ещё и  понравилось:-)

Comment: не работает этот код, min(start_date) по столбцу все равно выбирает в подзапросе